# Javascript/JQuery not showing up on github pages site

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, github-pages

I recently made some changes to an old (1yo) node app that is hosted by gh-pages.  I deleted the remote gh-pages branch and pushed up the new version.  For some reason the Javascript and JQuery is not loading.  For example I have some text that is prepended to a div, and it's not showing up:

```
$('#othello-right').prepend(`<h1>ello</h1>`)
```

Comment: browser developer tools console - look for errors, perhaps

Comment: No errors, but on both production and local it has a deprecation warning: 
```'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead```
It works fine locally.
I don't know if this is unusual, but under sources in dev tools, I don't see all the files that are supposed to be there.  They're on the gh-pages branch though on github.

Comment: Is it possible that this is due to github switching to http for gh-pages?

Comment: http or did you mean https?

Comment: Ok, it was an old app and I had to reinstall jquery.  Now it works.  Yes I meant https.  Thank you Jaromanda for your replies :)